# CSS word-wrap: break-word not wrapping a tag unless you wrap it in div and add rule there

Tags: html, css, text, anchor, word-wrap

why does CSS rule

```
a {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

with

```
<div>
  <a href="...">verylongurlherewithnospaces</a>
</div>
```

not wrapping and causing window to show scrollbar, whereas

```
div {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

will do the wrapping at its anchor child's text fine?

**UPDATE:**
just noticed (see L3ST-instance URL field at this [form](http://gallery.trafilm.net/L3STinstance/metadata/?film=FellowshipOfTheRing&conversation=FellowshipOfTheRing.Arwen_Bruinen_spell&L3STinstance=FellowshipOfTheRing.Arwen_Bruinen_spell.Casting_the_spell) when you resize the window) that I needed word-break:break-all instead of word-wrap:break-word, apart from the suggested display:inline-block, so now using:

```
a
{
  word-break: break-all !important; /* make sure containers don't override */
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

which works fine

Comment: I would assume you have a fixed width set for your div?

Comment: some upper div parent of it is 100%

Comment: seems the issue is the "display" style of the anchors (see answer below), however wonder if this design choice is intuitive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSS `word-wrap: break-word;` works only in `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;` elements so you can just use:

```
a {
  display:inline-block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```css
a {
  width:100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="...">verylongurlherewithnospaces</a>
</div>
```

P.S. `div` are `display:block;` as default by user-agent.

Comment: thanks, is there some specific rationale behind that design choice?

Comment: My thought is that word-wrap was made for block level elements not inline elements.  It is impossible to overflow an inline element.  Which is why word-wrap exists to prevent the content from overflow the block level element.  I think using it on the DIV is probably more correct.

Comment: Probably because you can set a width on block-level elements. Naturally inline elements (like `a`) don't have a fixable width and will expand to contain their content.

Comment: @Dave Cripps - indeed, thanks for your comment - this question where one wants to set a width to anchor is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743254/setting-a-width-and-height-on-an-a-tag

Comment: there are some interesting comments btw in that other question, like that putting such anchors inside UL list will break ones rules (in Chrome) and will have to set them inline or I guess use !important. They also have a pointer to the spec in some other comment http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop

Comment: @George Birbilis - Your welcome. :) Yes indeed, and some of the responses to that question have it -- you need to change the inline element to display as a block-level element to set a size.

Comment: just in case that comment on UL overriding one's rules in Chrome I used !important. Also I found out that word-wrap:break-word wasn't doing the job and used word-break:break-all instead. Can see it working at the form I mention in the update section at the end of the original question